# Cakephp-3.0 Possible to redirect immediately?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So a change was made to Controller::redirect and now it fires AFTER your controller action is called. So if you're wanting to redirect someone (that's not logged in for example) before logic is fired that is no longer possible. Does anyone know how to simulate the old 2.X behavior where a call to Controller::redirect would immediately stop everything and redirected?

Comment: Can you not just call it via `$this->redirect('...')` inside your controller action? (not sure on the syntax)

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages**

Comment: It looks like returning after the redirect might work, however; I'm calling it from a method called from the controller... so that does not solve my issue.

Comment: Then return the return value of that method, or use events, or whatever may be appropriate in your secret scenario...

Comment: You should already have used "return" for all redirects even in 2.x apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to `return` the `$this->redirect()` call, that will return a response object immediately from the controller that will make the Dispatcher understand that you want to terminante the request immediately:

```
return $this->redirect($url);
```

The redirect can be done from the controller action itself or any of the callbacks in the controller (`beforeFilter`, `beforeRender`, `afterFilter` ...). Returning the redirect value is also allowed from any of the component callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible ways to redirect user if he not logged in. I did it one of my app. First is using beforeFilter() of a controller. You could use like

```
public function beforeFilter(){
 parent::beforeFilter();
 if(empty($this->logged_in)){
   //your redirect code or your logic
 }
}
```

It executes at very first time when your controller action is being called. 
Second you can create a class's constructor function. It executes also at very first.

```
public function __construct( $request = null, $response = null ) {
    parent::__construct( $request = null, $response = null );
    //Your redirect code if user not logged in
}
```

You can write your code in AppController beforeFilter(); But if you only want to prevent non logged in users to access some function, you should use Auth component allow function. Syntax is

```
$this->Auth->allow(array('action_name_1','action_name2'));
```

Paste this allow function in beforeFilter function. By using above tricks you can prevent user to access your logic if he / she not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. And I ended up with good old `header()` function along with `die()`

```
header('Location: http://example.com/whatever');  
die;
```